# How to understand this regular expression

Tags: regex

i know `{min,max}`, however,i can't understand `{{.*?}}`.

Comment: put your regex in regex editor like https://regex101.com/. It will explain every portion of it.

Comment: Oh bother, again hit reopen instead of delete... Please close with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that:

1. `{{` matches literally
2. `.` matches any except line term.
3. `*?` [Lazy Quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), matches as few characters as possible.
4. `}}` matches literally

Comment: to match {,i don't have to write \{?